# add 1 day with an given date

Tags: javascript, date

please consider below scenario:-

```
var d = new Date(); 

var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();

var output = d.getFullYear() + '-' +
    ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +
    ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day;//alert(output);

var incept_dt = new Date();
var incept_dt = "2014-01-04";
```

I want to increase 1 day in incept_dt. i.e my expected incep_dt would be :-

```
var incept_dt = "2014-01-05";
```

I've tried below:-

```
incept_dt = incept_dt.setDate(incept_dt.getDate() + 1);
```

But getting below error:-

**TypeError: incept_dt.getDate is not a function
incept_dt = incept_dt.setDate(incept_dt.getDate() + 1);**

Any suggestion please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: after edit still it is wrong, plz see answer below to initialize date.

Comment: Nope, still not converting to a Date object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to get my exact answer of my question I do the following:-

```
var incept_dt = new Date(); 
var incept_dt = new Date("2014-01-04");

incept_dt = incept_dt.setDate(incept_dt.getDate() + 1);
incept_dt = new Date(incept_dt);
var incept_month = (incept_dt.getMonth()+1);
var incept_day = incept_dt.getDate();
incept_dt = incept_dt.getFullYear() + '-' + 
           ((''+incept_month).length<2 ? '0' : '') +incept_month + '-' +
           ((''+incept_day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + incept_day;
```

NOTE:- For conversion to time, I get concept from @Ravinder 's post.

Comment: Hey, I'd like to help you a bit more, I'm not a spiteful person :D So, you can remove the first line of your script, and you can replace `incept_dt = incept_dt.setDate(...)` with `incept_dt.setDate(...)`, this allows to remove the next line. Peace :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
var incept_dt = new Date(2014, 1, 4);
var daysToAdd = 1;
incept_dt.setDate( incept_dt.getDate() + daysToAdd );
```

To change the *display format* of a date, you can try the following way:

```
var fullYear = incept_dt.getFullYear().toString();
var _year = fullYear.substring( 2 );

var _month = incept_dt.getMonth().toString();
_month = _month.lenth > 1 ? _month : ( '0' + _month );

var _date = incept_dt.getDate().toString();
_date = _date.length > 1 ? _date : ( '0' + _date );

// use this wherever you want.  
var date_to_display = _year + "-" + _month + "-" + _date;

//alert( date_to_display );
```

Comment: yes. it's working. But returning time. How will I get YY-MM-DD?

Answer (score 1):

What about adding 24h?

```
var date = new Date;
date = new Date(+date + 3600000 * 24);
```

Or, using `get/setDate` :

```
var date = new Date;
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
```

Here is a function to format a date object :

```
function format(date) {
    return [
        date.getFullYear(),
        ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
        ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2)
    ].join('-')
}
```

Usage example (gives today's date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format) :

```
format(new Date) // "2014-01-02"
```

All together :

```
var date = '2014-01-04';
date = new Date(date);
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
date = format(date); // "2014-01-05"
```

Comment: @ripa `date` must be a date object. Answer clarified.

Comment: @ripa I've added some details.

Comment: @ripa I observe that you didn't accept any answer. Is there anything we could do in order to help you in resolving your problem?

Comment: I can't. You edited Your question after posting my answer. I havn't found any help from Your answer before posting my answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

because your variable is string not a date object.

try:

```
var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
```

Here is your updated code:

```
var incept_dt= new Date('2014-05-01');
incept_dt.setDate(incept_dt.getDate() + 1);
```

### After Post Edit

after your edit it still a string not date:

```
var incept_dt = new Date();
var incept_dt = "2014-01-04";
```

you initialize date then make it a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `incept_dt` from a string to a date before you can use Date functions.

```
incept_dt = new Date(incept_dt); //Convert to Date
incept_dt.setDate(incept_dt.getDate()+1); //Add one day
incept_dt = incept_dt.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + (incept_dt.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' + incept_dt.getUTCDate(); //Convert back to string
```

Comment: giving "TypeError: incept_dt.getUTCFullYear is not a function" this error.

Comment: Did you include the first line to convert it to a Date object? getUTCFullYear isn't a string function.

Answer (score 0):

Because `incept_dt` is a `string` variable not `Date` type.  So first convert it to `Date` type and then add the date.

First you have to *parse* your `string` date to `Date`.

```
var incept_dt = "2014-01-05".split("-");
var in_date = new Date(incept_dt[0], incept_dt[1], incept_dt[2])
```

Now you can perform your `Date` methods operations.

```
in_date.setDate(in_date.getDate() + 1)
```

Finally,

```
var incept_dt = "2014-01-05".split("-");
var in_date = new Date(incept_dt[0], incept_dt[1], incept_dt[2])
in_date.setDate(in_date.getDate() + 1)
console.log(in_date)
var yy = in_date.getFullYear();
var mm = in_date.getMonth() + 1;
var dd = in_date.getDate();
var final_Date = yy + "-"+ mm + "-"+ dd;
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qbGh5/1/)

Comment: yes. I also tried to make it date type. but didn't work. check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

As incept_dt  is a variable so to convert it to date do

```
var date = new Date(incept_dt); // convert string to date
```

As you are using ISO-Format YYYY-MM-DD, you dont have to worry about formatting it

If you want format, you can do

```
var dd = date.getDate();
var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
var y = date.getFullYear();

var som_date = dd + '/'+ mm + '/'+ y;
```

Then to add days like this

```
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 6;
date.setDate(date + numberOfDaysToAdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) and you won't have to jump through so many hoops.

```
// create a moment from your start date string
var m = moment('2014-01-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD');

// add a day
m.add(1, 'days');

// get a new string
var s = m.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

// or if you need a Date object
var dt = m.toDate();
```